# changing the default home & power buttons behaviours on Note 3

Tags: home-button, samsung-galaxy-note-3

Is there a way that I can configure the following?

- double press on the home button shows the recently opened apps. (by default, a double press  does that)
- long press on the home button triggers the voice search  (by default, a double press  does that)
- long press on the power-off button gives me the recently running apps(by default, it gives me the DEVICE OPTIONS ( poweroff+airplne mode etc...)
- alternatively, long press on the power-off button gives me an option to create an action list of my own which may contain items like 
  +turn off the phone, 
  +open app voice recorder 
  +start google search
  +even a "go back" function...

Is there a way in note 3 to get a handle of these functions/actions in terms of a shortcode handle name and then use it in making a list like that? ( I hope this part is not too confusing to you )

What's the ultimate tool/approach that lets one do these such fundamental changes in the way note 3 buttons work?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure concerning the Note-3 specifically, but there are some apps claiming to help you at least parically on this issue:

- [Button Savior (Root)](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Button-Savior-Root/com.smart.swkey)
- [Home2 Shortcut](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Home2-Shortcut/com.eikatou0.appspot.home2shortcut)
- [ButtonRemapper](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=850464)

They all have in common that they help you remapping one or more buttons.